# How do I graduate a cylinder glass in milliliters?

Tags: volume

Today I decided to cook something, but then I realized there is a critical item missing − a measuring glass. Being a programmer and all, I decided this wouldn't be much of a problem, as I could probably graduate it knowing its radius and height.

Height is 10cm and radius is 6cm. From the formula `V = pi*r^2*h` [I got 1.13097336 liters](https://www.google.com/search?q=pi%20%2a%20%286cm%29%20%5E%202%20%2a%2010cm), which is not possible because its volume is definitely below 0.5 liters.

I'd like to know how could I mess up such a simple formula, and then I'd like to figure out a way to graduate the glass knowing its volume, preferably in 25ml increments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yours calculations are correct, given the measures you've provided us. Maybe 6cm is the *diameter* of the container, so its radius is 3. That would make the volume you calculated go down by a factor of 4, making it  282.7 ml. Given your constraint that it is definitely below 0.5 liters, that seems correct.

About the increments, you could calculate the height of a cylinder whose volume is 25ml and radius is r, and then use a ruler to make marks.

h = V/(pi*r^2). Remember to use the correct units. For a radius of 0.03 meters (3cm), that would be approximately 0.00884194128 meters, or 0.88 cm.

Comment: Oh, right! I forgot that radius is diameter/2

Comment: Dear user, I appreciate so much your candidness in admitting that you "forgot that radius is diameter/2" that I upvoted your question. Another reason is the optimism that you display in stating that, for a programmer bent on cooking, not having a measuring glass is not "much of a  problem" :-)

Comment: In the end of a long day of experimenting, what was supposed to be udon noodles became an inedible mass of undercooked dough, but I learned a lot from this experience. Most importantly, it doesn't matter how precise a cooking recipe is − there's no way it's gonna work without lots of adjustments. Just like programming!